# Mysql query (Where) with an edittext android

Tags: android, mysql, android-edittext

I have this code to fill a listview with a json query, and works fine, but I want fill that view with a where query writed in a edittext, for example: Select * from tabla where name=(edittext).

```
class AsyncExecute extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         try {
                // Llamamos al servicio web para recuperar los datos
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://comupunt.esy.es/nombreb.php");
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse)httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                BufferedHttpEntity buffer = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                InputStream iStream = buffer.getContent();

                String aux = "";

                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                  aux += line;
                }

                // Parseamos la respuesta obtenida del servidor a un objeto JSON    
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(aux);
                JSONArray cities = jsonObject.getJSONArray("cities");

                // Recorremos el array con los elementos cities
                for(int i = 0; i < cities.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject city = cities.getJSONObject(i);

                  // Creamos el objeto City
                  City c = new City(city.getString("name"),   
                 city.getInt("nametwo"),city.getString("posicion") );
                  c.setData(city.getString("photo"));


                  listaPersonas.add(c.photo);
                  // Almacenamos el objeto en el array que hemos creado anteriormente
                  citiesAvaiable.add(c);

                }
              }
              catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Did you put the `JSONObject` into a database? The MySql query assumes you have a database and you don't show that.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
String mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
String EditTextValue = mEditText.getText.toString();
```

then pass this `EditTextValue` in where condition

Comment: then, how pass a variable into the json?